# Poetry self update hangs

Tags: python, python-poetry

When running `poetry update`, as well as other related commands, I get the process stuck at

```
Resolving dependencies...
```

I'm using poetry version 1.2.2, so I wanted to upgrade it by running `poetry self update -vvv`

The process hangs indefinitely at this point

```
Source (PyPI): Downloading sdist: msgpack-1.0.4.tar.gz
Creating new session for files.pythonhosted.org
```

If it is a bug, is there a workaround to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to remove poetry using pip: it was installed using pip so any other 'uninstall' method was ineffective.

```
pip uninstall poetry
```

Then I re-installed it with the following command:

```
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
```

It seems there is a bug in poetry 1.2 causing this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Either your local network has issues or PyPi has problems.

I suggest trying with a different Internet connection first, because diagnosing local network issues is very complicated on a discussion forum or remote generally.